# the meaning of this line in a service created using sysintv

Tags: shell-script

I'm creating a fake service with sysvinit. Inside the file I have created under `/etc/init.d/service_fake`

I got this line:

```
. /etc/sysconfig/fake_service
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 2):

`.` is shell for "source" so `. /etc/sysconfig/fake_service` reads the contents of that file and executes the shell code therein within the context of the process performing the source. Typically `/etc/sysconfig/fake_service` might contain statements such as

```
LICENSE_FOO=bar
```

or even arbitrary shell code, but it's usually mostly for setting environment variables (e.g. license details, timezone or local settings, etc).